# How can I import a repository into an Azure DevOps Project using SSH?

Tags: git, azure-devops, gitlab, ssh-keys

I'm trying to migrate a bunch of projects from a corporate Gitlab account to Azure DevOps. Az Devops has a handy "Import a repository" option... but it only has a field for a Clone URL (ie https).

[image: Import a Git Repository]

Is there a way for me to use SSH? The Gitlab account I'm migrating from has HTTPS disabled.

I added my SSH key to Az Devops, tried using the SSH link in the field, tried using a hand-crafted https (obviously didn't work).

I tried finding a command to do it from Git CLI but couldn't find anything. The closest I've found is creating a brand new repo, copying everything from the old repo, and pushing to the new one.

Comment: ... and what's wrong with that approach that you last described?

Comment: @eftshift0 It does not carry over all the branches ie develop, master.

Comment: Use the same process that GitHub describe, i.e., do a bare clone of the source and a `git push --mirror` to the destination. (You can even do a mirror clone of the source and a mirror push, but usually that will result in some complaints, given the way most hosting services work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH authentication is not supported, but you can manually import a repository that uses SSH authentication by following the steps using git CLI.
The reference document is here:[Import a Git repo into your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#manual-import-git-cli)

1 Clone the source repo to a temporary folder on your computer

```
git clone git@github.com:{your account} /demo.git
cd demo.git
```

2 Run the following command to copy the source repo to the target repo.

```
  git push --mirror https://dev.azure.com/{organization name} /{project name} /_git/{target repo name}
```